# Open Jint solution correctly

Tags: visual-studio-2012, jint

I need to open the Jint solution downloaded from here :
https://github.com/sebastienros/jint 
(i've downloaded the zip with all the files, later i decompressed them and then i try to open the solution's file using visual studio)

Visual Studio (both 2012 Express and 2013 Express) tell me that the main project is not compatibile, i have tried Microsoft Visual Studio Version Selector but still not working.
Anybody can tell me why this happen and how i can open and view that solution with all its projects properly loaded?

Here a screen of my situation :
[image: visual studio solution does not load a project becaouse not comnpatible]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This project targets the Portable Framework. You might need to install the Windows Phone SDK or some other component depending on your version of Visual Studio. Please refer to [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391(v=vs.110).aspx) for more details.

Comment: Ah sorry, i have not read that it's only for NET CF.

So it not suit for my pourpose, thanks anyway.

Comment: It's not! Targeting the PCL will let you use it on all the .NET platforms. We use the least common denominator of all .NET platforms so that it works everywhere.

Comment: Try to install Visual Studio 2015 community edition.